# Making a macro execute automatically on any changes to cell value

Tags: updatemodel, automatic-updates

I have prepared a big spreadsheet and I want that if any of the inputs for the spreadsheet are changed by the user, the module runs automatically to update the sheet.

```
Sub Biomass()
Cells(5, 4).Value = Cells(10, 17).Value
Cells(4, 1).Value = 0
Cells(5, 1).Value = 1
Cells(4, 6).Value = Cells(1, 17).Value * 50000
Cells(5, 8).Value = Cells(5, 17).Value * 12
Dim c As Long
c = Cells(1, 10).Value * Cells(4, 6).Value
cntr = 0
For i = 6 To (Cells(1, 7).Value + 4)
Cells(i, 4).Value = Cells(i - 1, 4).Value * (1 + Cells(11, 17).Value)
Cells(i, 1).Value = i - 4
Cells(i - 1, 6).Value = Cells(4, 6).Value - ((i - 5) * c)
Cells(i, 6).Value = Cells(4, 6).Value - ((i - 4) * c)
Cells(i - 1, 7).Value = Cells(i - 1, 6).Value / (1 + Cells(1, 2).Value) ^ (i - 5)
Cells(i, 7).Value = Cells(i, 6).Value / (1 + Cells(1, 2).Value) ^ (i - 4)
Cells(i - 1, 5).Value = (Cells(i - 1, 4).Value / (1 + Cells(1, 2).Value) ^ (i - 5)) + Cells(i - 2, 5)
Cells(i, 5).Value = (Cells(i, 4).Value / (1 + Cells(1, 2).Value) ^ (i - 4)) + Cells(i - 1, 5)
Cells(i, 8).Value = Cells(i - 1, 8).Value * (1 - Cells(13, 17).Value)
Cells(i - 1, 9).Value = Cells(i - 1, 8).Value / ((1 + Cells(1, 2).Value) ^ (i - 5))
Cells(i, 9).Value = Cells(i, 8).Value / ((1 + Cells(1, 2).Value) ^ (i - 4))

Cells(5, 10).Value = Cells(5, 9).Value
Cells(i, 10).Value = Cells(i - 1, 10).Value + Cells(i, 9).Value
Cells(i - 1, 11).Value = Cells(14, 17).Value / (1 + Cells(1, 2).Value) ^ (i - 5)
Cells(i, 11).Value = Cells(14, 17).Value / (1 + Cells(1, 2).Value) ^ (i - 4)
Cells(4, 12).Value = 0
Cells(i - 1, 12) = Cells(i - 2, 12).Value + Cells(i - 1, 11).Value
Cells(i, 12).Value = Cells(i - 1, 12).Value + Cells(i, 11).Value
Cells(i - 1, 13).Value = (Cells(2, 17).Value + Cells(i - 1, 5).Value - Cells(i - 1, 12).Value - Cells(i - 1, 7).Value) / Cells(i - 1, 10).Value
Cells(i, 13).Value = (Cells(2, 17).Value + Cells(i, 5).Value - Cells(i, 12).Value - Cells(i, 7).Value) / Cells(i, 10).Value
cntr = cntr + 1
If cntr = 24 Then Exit For
Next i

For g = 5 To (Cells(35, 17).Value + 4)
Cells(g, 3).Value = Cells(36, 17).Value
Next g


cntr2 = 0
For d = 5 To (Cells(1, 7).Value + 4)
Cells(d, 2).Value = Cells(21, 17).Value * Cells(d, 8).Value + Cells(d, 3).Value - Cells(d, 4).Value
cntr2 = cntr2 + 1
If cntr2 = 25 Then Exit For
Next d

cntr3 = 0
For i = (cntr + 7) To (Cells(1, 7).Value + 4)
Cells(30, 6).Value = Cells(4, 6).Value * (1 + Cells(1, 4).Value) ^ 30
c2 = Cells(1, 10).Value * Cells(30, 6).Value
Cells(30, 4).Value = Cells(5, 4).Value
Cells(i, 4).Value = Cells(i - 1, 4).Value * (1 + Cells(11, 17).Value)
Cells(i, 1).Value = i - 4
Cells(i, 6).Value = Cells(30, 6).Value - ((i - 30) * c2)
Cells(i - 1, 7).Value = Cells(i - 1, 6).Value / (1 + Cells(1, 2).Value) ^ (i - 5)
Cells(i, 7).Value = Cells(i, 6).Value / (1 + Cells(1, 2).Value) ^ (i - 4)
Cells(i - 1, 5).Value = (Cells(i - 1, 4).Value / (1 + Cells(1, 2).Value) ^ (i - 5)) + Cells(i - 2, 5)
Cells(i, 5).Value = (Cells(i, 4).Value / (1 + Cells(1, 2).Value) ^ (i - 4)) + Cells(i - 1, 5)
Cells(30, 8).Value = Cells(5, 8).Value
Cells(i, 8).Value = Cells(i - 1, 8).Value * (1 - Cells(13, 17).Value)
Cells(i - 1, 9).Value = Cells(i - 1, 8).Value / ((1 + Cells(1, 2).Value) ^ (i - 5))
Cells(i, 9).Value = Cells(i, 8).Value / ((1 + Cells(1, 2).Value) ^ (i - 4))

Cells(30, 10).Value = Cells(30, 9).Value + Cells(29, 10).Value
Cells(i, 10).Value = Cells(i - 1, 10).Value + Cells(i, 9).Value
Cells(i - 1, 11).Value = Cells(14, 17).Value / (1 + Cells(1, 2).Value) ^ (i - 5)
Cells(i, 11).Value = Cells(14, 17).Value / (1 + Cells(1, 2).Value) ^ (i - 4)
Cells(i - 1, 12) = Cells(i - 2, 12).Value + Cells(i - 1, 11).Value
Cells(i, 12).Value = Cells(i - 1, 12).Value + Cells(i, 11).Value
Cells(i - 1, 13).Value = (Cells(2, 17).Value + Cells(i - 1, 5).Value - Cells(i - 1, 12).Value - Cells(i - 1, 7).Value) / Cells(i - 1, 10).Value
Cells(i, 13).Value = (Cells(2, 17).Value + Cells(i, 5).Value - Cells(i, 12).Value - Cells(i, 7).Value) / Cells(i, 10).Value
cntr3 = cntr3 + 1
If cntr3 = 25 Then Exit For
Next i


cntr4 = 0
For d = 30 To (Cells(1, 7).Value + 4)
Cells(d, 2).Value = Cells(21, 17).Value * Cells(d, 8).Value + Cells(d, 3).Value - Cells(d, 4).Value
cntr4 = cntr4 + 1
If cntr4 = 25 Then Exit For
Next d

End Sub
```

As you can see, cells(10,17)(1,17)(25,17)(5,17)(17,17)(4,6)(11,17)(5,9)(1,7)(24,17)(5,10) are the cells on changing any of which the sub should run automatically.

Answer (score 0):

The following should be able to solve your problem.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim KeyCells As Range

    Set KeyCells = Range("INPUT RANGE")

    If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCells, Range(Target.Address)) _
           Is Nothing Then
            ' YOUR CODE GOES HERE
    End If
End Sub
```

Just change the INPUT RANGE and input your code where I have marked.

Comment: My inputs are not exactly contiguous..They are spread over the entire sheet...Is there a way I can select individual cells not close together?

Comment: I would select all the cells that are part of the input and set them as a named range and then just use the name of the named range inplace of INPUT RANGE.

Comment: Is it possible to nest my subroutine under the private subroutine that you just provided above? I tried it but I gor a compile error

Comment: Can you edit your OP to include your current code and I can have a look. You can't really nest it within the `sub` but if you write it proceeding then you can use it by `call yourOtherSub` where `' YOUR CODE GOES HERE` has been written.